# How do I set bot mention as a bot prefix? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, prefix

I set up my bot to be able to have custom prefixes, and now I want my bot to be able to respond when someone mentions it. It should respond both when someone `@bot` or `@bot help`.

```
def get_prefix(client, message): 
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f: ##we open and read the prefixes.json, assuming it's in the same file
        prefixes = json.load(f) #load the json as prefixes
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] #recieve the prefix for the guild id given

client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix= (get_prefix),
    intents = intents
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
def get_prefix(client, message): 
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f: ##we open and read the prefixes.json, assuming it's in the same file
        prefixes = json.load(f) #load the json as prefixes
    prefix = prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
    return when_mentioned_or(*prefix)(client, message) #recieve the prefix for the guild id given

client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix= (get_prefix),
    intents = intents
    )

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    mention = f'<@!{client.user.id}>'
    if message.content == mention:
        with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f: ##we open and read the prefixes.json, assuming it's in the same file
         prefixes = json.load(f) #load the json as prefixes
        prefix = prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
        await message.channel.send(f"You called? My prefix for this server is `{prefix}`. Admins can change it by using `{prefix}changeprefix <new prefix>`")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i got what you are trying to ask according to @Bruce21 thats a long method and it doesnt respond to like `@bot help` . i have a simple method.

Try : `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= when_mentioned_or(get_prefix), intents = intents)`

Comment: If it works, pls consider marking it as accepted answer